# switchMap in ngrx effects with Angular 6+ throws type error

Tags: angular6, ngrx

I have written an effect in my Angular 6 + Ngrx application, however it throws the following error.

Argument of type `Observable<RouteSuccessAction>` is not assignable to parameter of type `<value: never, index: number> => ObservableInput<Action>`

Following are the code snippets.

route.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteEffect {
    constructor(private actions: Actions, private routeService: RouteService) {
    }

    @Effect()
    getRoutes$: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(RouteActions.RouteActionTypes.ROUTE_LOAD), switchMap(
            this.routeService.getRoutes().pipe(
                map(routes => new RouteActions.RouteSuccessAction(routes.route))
            )
        )
    );
}
```

route.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Route } from '../model';
export enum RouteActionTypes {
    GET_ROUTE = '[GET ROUTE] GET',
    ROUTE_FAIL = '[ROUTE_FAIL] FAIL',
    ROUTE_SUCCESS = '[ROUTE_SUCCESS] SUCCESS',
    ROUTE_LOAD = '[ROUTE_LOAD] LOAD',

}

export class GetRouteAction implements Action {
    readonly type = RouteActionTypes.GET_ROUTE;

}
export class RouteSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = RouteActionTypes.ROUTE_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Route[]) {
    }

}
export class RouteFailureAction implements Action {
    readonly type = RouteActionTypes.ROUTE_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) {
    }

}
export type RouteActions = GetRouteAction | RouteSuccessAction | RouteFailureAction;
```

route.model.ts

```
export interface Route {
  'referringURL': string;
  'routeName': string;
  'visible': boolean;
}
```

Service return the following response

```
    [
        {
            "referringURL": "",
            "routeName": "route1",
            "visible": true
        },
        {
            "referringURL": "",
            "routeName": "route2",
            "visible": true
        },
        {
            "referringURL": "",
            "routeName": "route3",
            "visible": true
        }
]
```

Comment: please post the piece of code related to this error.

Comment: Daniel, I have posted it.

Answer (score 4):

Your switchmap isn't a function it should be

```
switchMap(() => ...)
```

Comment: Oh! my bad. Thank you so much.